# DIV flow and border issue

Tags: html, css

What's wrong with the code. The border is faulty.

```
<div id="contents" style="width: 50%; height: auto; margin: 0 auto; left: 50%; border: 2px solid #73AD21;">
    <div id="USER" style="margin: 5px">
        <p style="width: 50%; text-align:left; padding-left: 1%; float: right; font-size: large"> user :</p>
        <input id="txt_ID" type="text" style="width: 45%; float: left"/>
    </div>
    <div id="PASS" style="margin: 5px">
        <p style="width: 50%; text-align:left; padding-left: 1%; float: right; font-size: large">pass :</p>
        <input id="txt_Password" type="text" style="width: 45%; float: left"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is 'faulty' about the border?

Comment: @Starscream1984 border isn't drawn around other div's inside. It's just a line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using floats in the inner divs so the parent has no height. Just set `float: left;` to the `contents` div and you see your problem.

```html
<div id="contents" style="width: 50%; height: auto; margin: 0 auto; float: left; left: 50%; border: 2px solid #73AD21;">
  <div id="USER" style="margin: 5px">
    <p style="width: 50%; text-align:left; padding-left: 1%; float: right; font-size: large"> user :</p>
    <input id="txt_ID" type="text" style="width: 45%; float: left"/>
  </div>
  <div id="PASS" style="margin: 5px">
    <p style="width: 50%; text-align:left; padding-left: 1%; float: right; font-size: large">pass :</p>
    <input id="txt_Password" type="text" style="width: 45%; float: left"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

You should probably not use inline-css but rather have a external css-file and use clearfix to clear floats on the `contents` div instead.

Comment: I am adding arabic contents it written right to left. so the flow is right

Comment: Yes I'm not talking about your float being right or wrong. You just need to float the parent or something else for it to be able to have height which leads to the borders to be correct :)

Answer (score 0):

You using `float` elements so add `clear: both` before main div end

```
<div id="contents" style="width: 50%; height: auto; margin: 0 auto; left: 50%; border: 2px solid #73AD21;">
    <div id="USER" style="margin: 5px">
        <p style="width: 50%; text-align:left; padding-left: 1%; float: right; font-size: large"> user :</p>
        <input id="txt_ID" type="text" style="width: 45%; float: left"/>
    </div>
    <div id="PASS" style="margin: 5px">
        <p style="width: 50%; text-align:left; padding-left: 1%; float: right; font-size: large">pass :</p>
        <input id="txt_Password" type="text" style="width: 45%; float: left"/>
    </div>
    <div style="clear: both"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to clear floats.

Add following css

```
#contents:after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear:both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply `#contents { float: left}` or use clear float trick for parent to take inner element height:

```css
#contents {
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  left: 50%;
  border: 2px solid #73AD21;
}
#contents:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
#contents > div {
  margin: 5px;
}
#contents p {
  width: 50%;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 1%;
  float: right;
  font-size: large;
}
#contents input {
  width: 45%;
  float: left
}
```

```html
<div id="contents">
  <div id="USER">
    <p>user :</p>
    <input id="txt_ID" type="text" />
  </div>
  <div id="PASS">
    <p>pass :</p>
    <input id="txt_Password" type="text" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're using `float` - this takes the element out of the normal flow, because everything is floated, the outer div has no height.

Use `display: inline-block` instead:

```
<div id="contents" style="width: 50%; height: auto; margin: 0 auto; left: 50%; border: 2px solid #73AD21;">
    <div id="USER" style="margin: 5px">
        <p style="width: 50%; text-align:left; padding-left: 1%; font-size: large; display: inline-block;"> user :</p>
        <input id="txt_ID" type="text" style="width: 45%; display: inline-block;"/>
    </div>
    <div id="PASS" style="margin: 5px">
        <p style="width: 50%; text-align:left; padding-left: 1%; font-size: large; display: inline-block;">pass :</p>
        <input id="txt_Password" type="text" style="width: 45%; display: inline-block;"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

[link to fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4bexnajc/)

Answer (score 0):

Your parent container is being collapsed by its `float`ed children. I recommend using a clearfix class:

```css
.cf:before,
.cf:after {
    content: " "; /* 1 */
    display: table; /* 2 */
}

.cf:after {
    clear: both;
}

/**
 * For IE 6/7 only
 * Include this rule to trigger hasLayout and contain floats.
 */
.cf {
    *zoom: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="cf" id="contents" style="width: 50%; height: auto; margin: 0 auto; left: 50%; border: 2px solid #73AD21;">
    <div id="USER" style="margin: 5px">
        <p style="width: 50%; text-align:left; padding-left: 1%; float: right; font-size: large"> user :</p>
        <input id="txt_ID" type="text" style="width: 45%; float: left"/>
    </div>
    <div id="PASS" style="margin: 5px">
        <p style="width: 50%; text-align:left; padding-left: 1%; float: right; font-size: large">pass :</p>
        <input id="txt_Password" type="text" style="width: 45%; float: left"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Clearfix source: http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/

Info on clearfix: [What is a clearfix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554043/what-is-clearfix)